# Make exim send bounces from a non-empty address?

Tags: smtp, exim

Exim, by default, sends bounce messages using MAIL FROM:<>, which my upstream SMTP host rejects. I've seen options to add an AUTH= address to the MAIL FROM line, or to change the From: address on a bounce, but not to change the actual address in the MAIL FROM line; does this option exist, or any way to achieve that effect?

Comment: Bounces are supposed to come from <>. Perhaps you need to convince your upstream host to stop doing things wrong. http://rfc-ignorant.org/policy-dsn.php

Comment: Or you need to reject bogus messages during the SMTP delivery and then it will not be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty MAIL FROM:<> is perfectly legitimate, and the upstream SMTP host is the thing that needs fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming this is an old issue, please note that this can cause bounces with Amazon SES service. Its exactly [this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/604993/how-to-setup-exim-to-check-the-from-field) which we personally haven't solved as we endep up avoiding exim as forwarder